# Color gradient in graphics?

Tags: graphics, color

I would like to color gradient (Red to Blue) the following curve:

```
gr = Graphics[{Arrow[BezierCurve[{{0, 3}, {.8, 2}, {1.8, 1.7}}]]}]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, 
  Arrow[Line[
    BezierFunction[{{0, 3}, {.8, 2}, {1.8, 1.7}}] /@ Subdivide[50], 
    VertexColors -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, #] & /@ Subdivide[50])]]}]`?

Comment: @kglr Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @kglr Can the arrow also be made of blue color?

Comment: @kglr Got the arrow part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Arrowheads[.05], 
  Arrow[Line[BezierFunction[{{0, 3}, {.8, 2}, {1.8, 1.7}}] /@ Subdivide[100], 
    VertexColors -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, #] & /@ Subdivide[100])]]}]
```

[image]

To get a smoother look `Rasterize` using a large `ImageSize` and resize using `Magnify`:

```
Magnify[Rasterize[
  Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, Blue, AbsoluteThickness[20], 
    Arrowheads[.05], 
    Arrow[Line[BezierFunction[{{0, 3}, {.8, 2}, {1.8, 1.7}}] /@ Subdivide[100],
       VertexColors -> (Blend[{Red, Blue}, #] & /@ Subdivide[100])]]}], 
  ImageSize -> 5000], .1]
```

[image]